# why is L=[...]. not allowed in the source file?

Tags: prolog

I have a long list that I need to declare in the Data-Base. Can't I write:

```
L=[a,b,c,d,f].

f(t,g,r) :- w(L), ...
```

When I tray to compile it gives an error message. If I cancel the L= ... line it's ok. How do I declare a list in the source file?

Answer (score 3):

It's better not to assign to a global variable, and anyway that's the wrong syntax. Stay with plain Prolog, and add a 'declaration' predicate that holds your long list data.

```
my_list([a,b,c,d,f]).
```

that will be used like

```
f(t,g,r) :- my_list(L), w(L), ...
```

If you want also to use *existence* of data as 'already done' flag, you can use a pattern like

```
f(t,g,r) :- (retract(my_list(L))-> w(L) ; already_done_no_L_available), ...
```

but then you will need the *declaration*

```
:- dynamic(my_list/1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `L=[a,b,c,d,f].` line tries to define a clause for the `(=)/2` standard built-in predicate. As built-in predicates cannot normally be redefined, you receive a permission error when trying to compile the file. Note that, as `(=)/2` is also declared as a infix operator, that line is equivalent to:

```
'='(L, [a,b,c,d,f]).
```

If you need to represent the list in your file, you can simply chose a predicate name for the information it represents and add a fact for it as Carlo explained in his answer.